# Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. localhost

Tags: php, localhost, http-status-code-404

I have a typical set up A,M,P and i am just doing some testing on my localhost server for setting up a webpage. I'm a bit new to php and dynamic sites so I'm muddling my way though. So I am at an impasse here. Whenever I attempt to view the page in the browser and click on the links I get this error:

**Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7**

```
my url looks like this: http://localhost/test/content/home
```

here is the code for my index.php page and my nav.php page

first index.php

```
<?php
include('Config/setup.php');
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == !'') {
    $pg = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $pg = 'home';
}
#var_dump($pg);
#exit;
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

    <title>FTS</title>
    <link href="css/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="header temp_Block">
    <?php include('templates/header.php');?>
</div>

<div class="main_nav temp_Block">
    <?php include('templates/main_nav.php');?>
</div>

<div class="main_Content temp_Block">
    <?php include('Content/'.$pg.'.php');?>
</div>

<div class="footer temp_Block">
    <?php include('templates/footer.php');?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my nav.php

```
<?php include('Config/setup.php')?>

 <a href="/test/content/home">home</a>
 <a href="/test/content/freestuff">free stuff</a>
 <a href="/test/content/aboutus">about us</a>
 <a href="/test/content/services">services</a>
 <a href="/test/content/Whatwedobetter">What we do better</a>
```

I thought this might be a permissions problem because /content/home.php is in a subfolder in xxamp/htdocs/test. But I'm not entirely sure. I could test this on a hosting site which I have but the 404 error makes me think it might be something with localhost and not with my code.

Answer (score 12):

mostly this kind of error is caused by missing an .htaccess file in your root wordpress directory , however in order to check that , get in touch directly to the permalink structure and try to change your permalink and hit save , once you find the same error you should directly create an .htaccess file under wordpress root  and make its first permissions to 777 , then refresh your site an click save change on your permalink , once your site continue to run correctly as you were expected , you should right away comeback to your .htaccess and change it to 644 in order to secure your site , i believe that this happened in most wordpress permalink settings , hopefully it would be helpful for anyone who meet this kind of issue .

Comment: Helped a lot, i just went to dashboard -> settings -> permalinks then just hit save as it was already set properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specified your project as right way.

- So run your `XAMPP control panel` then start the `apache` and `MySQL`
- Then note the ports.
- For Example PORT 80: then you type your browser url as `localhost:80\` press enter now your php basic Config page is visible.
- Then create any folder on `xampp\htdocs\YourFloderName`  Then
  create php file then save it and go to browser then type it `localhost\YourFolderName` now it listed the files click the file and it runs.

Answer (score 1):

write in file config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8000/test/content/home/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Config/setup.php` file actually in `/test/content/home/` or is in your document root? it is best to make all references relative to your document root.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "Config/setup.php";
```

Your current code assumes that the location of `setup.php` is in `/text/content/home/Config/setup.php`, is this correct?

Comment: k ill try it...can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

First check what your php error reports tells you. And define application wide root at the biginning of your index.php

```
define ('APPROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

and then use it to include you files

```
include(APPROOT.'templates/header.php');
```

and so on...
And to you have you .htaccess
rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

Simply my project wasn't in htdocs thats why it was showing me an this error make sure you put your project in HTdocs not in directory inside it

Answer (score 0):

I also had same error but with codeigniter application. I changed

- my base URL in config.php to my localhost path
- in htaccess I changed RewriteBase /"my folder name in htdocs"

  and I able to login to my application.

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found out is that your folder holding your php/html files cannot be named the same name as the folder in your HTDOCS carrying your project.

Comment: But isn't the "folder holding your php/html files" the same as the "folder in your HTDOCS carrying your project"?

Comment: What I meant was the folder inside your htdocs folder will have a name and the files inside of that folder cannot have the same name as the original directory that contains the files

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering this on ***react frontend*** remove **method** from **form**

```
<form method="POST">
...rest of your code
</form>
```

to

```
<form>
...rest of your code
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

If the page you are visiting is index.php, then your url should look like

```
http://localhost/test/content/home/ OR http://localhost/test/content/home/index.php

not the way you specified - http://localhost/test/content/home
```