# Localhost/info.php is showing Object not found what to do?

Tags: php, localhost

I successfully installed xampp 1.8.3(windows-7-x64) and then started Apache server. I can access the server through `localhost` but can't see the `localhost/info.php` file. My friend also did the same and he can view the php info.

The error is

> ### Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> ### Error 404
>
> localhost
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6

I'm very new to this so maybe I'm asking silly question. Please bear with me.

Comment: The error is quite clear: there is no file called `info.php` inside your document root. Have you created it, is it readable by apache (should't be too much of a problem on windows though), and is it in the right directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046543/object-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-localhost

Comment: What happens when you enter this into your browser:  http://localhost/?phpinfo=1

Comment: @Bri the welcome tab of xampp.

Comment: Check to see if there is even an info.php file under C:\xampp\htdocs\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the htdocs directory in the xampp installation directory (e.g: C:\xampp\htdocs) whether there is a file name info.php. Maybe there is no such file. If so, create a file named info.php in the htdocs. To view your php info, replace the info.php content with this code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

After save file info.php in the htdocs directory, browse localhost/info.php again in your web browser.

Comment: There is an `index.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

create new page and name it whatever U want and write this code simply

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I got it there is a tab for phpinfo. No need for `info.php` file in htdocs.

[image]

However thanks for your inputs.