# Form Open redirect to 404 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing a form in my view. I have already created a Controller "Search" and there I have "doSearch()" function where I load a view.

```
<?php echo form_open('Search/doSearch'); ?>
```

I need to call that method in "Search" controller when I click the submit button.

When I click form submit button my request is direct in to

`http://localhost/mysite/index.php/Search/doSearch` page giving 404 error. How to solve this.

Code:

First View where I write my form

```
<html>
<body lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

<?php echo form_open('Search/doSearch'); ?>
    <center
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <input type="text" name="item"/>
            </td>
              <td>
                In
            </td>
              <td>
                 <input type="text" name="location"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</center>
 <br>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected controller to process the request for the form submission

```
<?php
class Search extends CI_Controller {

    public function doSearch()
    {
        $this->load->view('search_page');

    }
}
```

I have written "serch_page" view in my view. Once I click in search button, it firect to **http://localhost/mysite/index.phmysite/Search/doSearch** and give me

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

application/.htaccess file

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

routs.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Edit: I set entry in route.php and check every other location. Now I am getting following error in `http://localhost/mysite/Search/doSearch` page once i click form submit

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
```

Comment: Can you provide me your code view as a snippet here for deeply checking your issue?

Comment: if it's redirecting to `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/Search/search`, then maybe in the view u wrote `<?php form_open('Search/search')?>` and the method does not exist, check that.

Comment: @NASEEMFASAL added my code. Please check

Comment: You may need to set some routes in route.php

Comment: looks like .htaccess & route issue => /mysite/index.phmysite/Search/search

Comment: @ArashKiani added my .htaccess file

Comment: thats the wrong .htacess

Comment: try replacing the one next to index.php with this => <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: @ArashKiani Thanks, but didnt solve the issue.

Comment: can you add your routes

Comment: That url doesn't look right: http://localhost/mysite/index.phmysite/Search/search

Comment: @S.Imp Fixed the type

Comment: can you add $route['search'] = "Search/doSearch"; into it and let me know if what do you see in http://localhost/mysite/index.php/search

Comment: What is your base_url?

Comment: @Alex base URL is $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite';

Comment: Is your `Search` controller directly in your controllers directory like `/controllers/Search.php` or is it `/controllers/somedir/Search.php` ?(please note capitalizing the controller name both in the definition class Search and Search.php is a must as well) @S.Imp

Comment: Also try this .htaccess (might require you to restart apache) https://pastebin.com/jpzdWNRk

Comment: @Alex Restarted but not solved it. And my controller is in controllers folder. I edited my question posting the latest error

Comment: @Alex appears to be having problems determining what urls correspond to his controllers. What is the url of the form that you are working on? It might be helpful to see that. Also, can you tell us what url will actually show the search/dosearch controller?

Comment: After removing $index_page in config.php my form url is http://localhost/mysite/ and my submit button take me to http://localhost/mysite/Search/search object not found page

Comment: @Malintha it should be obvious that going to Search/search will not work because your controller's method is named doSearch. You need to be more careful and accurate in the information you provide.

Comment: Indeed and making routes is not going to solve the issue if you can't even access the page directly from the actual url.

Comment: "I have written "serch_page" view in my view. Once I click in search button" ..here the view page name is "serch_page", and in the  doSearch function the view page name is 'search_page', Please note the mismatching..you have to rename your view page name as search_page.php instead of  serch_page.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you need to start the action url in your call to form_helper with a slash. Instead of this:

```
<?php echo form_open('Search/doSearch'); ?>
```

Try this:

```
<?php echo form_open('/Search/doSearch'); ?>
```

I believe the issue is that any action url you supply that does **not** start with a slash is going to be interpreted as a [relative url](http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/seo-web-best-practices/relative-vs-absolute-urls-seo/) so if you were to display this form some other controller--say the url was http://localhost/mysite/index.php/controller/method --then your partial relative url Search/doSearch would end up submitting to http://localhost/mysite/index.php/controller/methodSearch/doSearch

**NOTE**: my answer here assumes that your Search.php is in the root of your controllers directory and not some subdirectory. If it's in some subdirectory, say application/controllers/subdir/Search.php, then you should do this:

```
<?php echo form_open('/subdir/Search/doSearch'); ?>
```

**EDIT**: looking more closely at your post, it would appear that your CodeIgniter project exists in a subdirectory, **mysite**, for some reason.  That being the case, try this:

```
<?php echo form_open('/mysite/Search/doSearch'); ?>
```

Comment: I dont think so as `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/Search/doSearch` is serving a 404, not `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/Search/Search/doSearch`

Comment: @Alex It's hard to tell what's really going on because your original post is confusing. It has typos, for instance "I have written "serch_page" view in my view. Once I click in search button, it firect to http://localhost/mysite/index.phmysite/Search/doSearch and give me". Unless I'm mistaken, the url appears to be preceded by mysite. I'm going to edit my post to make an adjustment.

Comment: @S.Imp form_open() uses no leading slash, as by docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_open#available-functions

Comment: @Vickel the document says no such thing.

Comment: @S.Imp maybe I'm mistaken, but the manual says `Here’s a simple example:

echo form_open('email/send');

The above example would create a form that points to your base URL plus the “email/send” URI segments, like this:

<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http://example.com/index.php/email/send">

`

Comment: @Vickel OK I think you are correct -- which is a bit weird IMHO. This function (which I almost never use) appears to concatenate the base_url from one's config preferences etc. Having experimented a bit, I don't think there's any harm in adding the leading slash. Malintha has been unable to tell us what the action url *should* be so it's a bit hard to tell him what PHP code to use.

Comment: @S.Imp the advantage of form_open() is that the form values will be automatically escaped. Concerning the problem, most likely it is the .htaccess file, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046543/object-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-localhost

Comment: @Vickel can you point me to the docs where it says this....pretty sure form open is just a convienience function to generate a <form> string with hidden csrf token field if enabled.

Comment: @Alex, don't understand your comment, anyway having a closer look at system/helpers/form_helper.php around line 101 talks about "Add CSRF field if enabled, but leave it out for GET requests and requests to external websites"

Comment: You said the advantage of using form oopen is that the values are automatically escaped. I&#39;m pretty sure that&#39;s done in query builder and isn&#39;t related to form open at all. I was merely stating what it actually is.

Comment: form != query builder, and I was just citing the official CI docs, at least that's how I understand it

Comment: query builder and form_open are two entirely different things. form_open will not escape any input values. all it does is create the opening `<form>` tag. If you supply an $attributes parameter (second parameter) then it will html_escape them if they are specified as an array. this function will also add the csrf token input, which is one of the few reasons to use it. I almost never do.

Comment: ah html escape is must be what vickel was referring to.. mind immediately went to queries

Comment: To get back to the OP's issue. I think we need for them to identify the *correct* url to which the form is supposed to submit. If s/he doesn't even know what that is, our chances of solving the problem are slim.

Comment: well its just a matter of making a controller called `Test` that extends `CI_Controller` and contains a function `some_function` and is called Test.php in `/controllers/Test.php` if the user then goes to `localhost/mysite/test/some_function` and doesn't get a 404 we know its just a simple typographical error somewhere and not a config issue (I'm leaning towards the former).

Comment: @Alex agreed. If we can get OP to identify the correct url, we might stand a chance.

Answer (score 0):

> "I have written "serch_page" view in my view. Once I click in search
>   button"

here the view page name is **"serch_page"**, and in the **doSearch** function the view page name is '**search_page**', Please note the mismatching..you have to rename your view page name as **search_page.php** instead of **serch_page.php**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of upper/lower characters you are using
try this, it should work:

```
<?php echo form_open('search/dosearch'); ?>
```