# How to fix 'The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated."

Tags: php, html

I have put my links in a href correctly, but once I click the particular item, after checking, the path doubles up.

This is for PHP/HTML wherein I've tried to put the entire path, but it still doubles up.

```
 <li> <a href="Products.php#SoftwareProducts" title="Software Portfolios">Software Portfolio</a></li> 
 <li><a href="products/enterprise/zeus.php" class="footer-content-link">BIDS</a></li>
 <li><a href="products/enterprise/zeus.php" class="footer-content-link">FIDS</a></li>
 <li><a href="products/enterprise/zeus.php" class="footer-content-link">GIDS</a></li>
 <li><a href="products/enterprise/zeus.php"class="footer-content-link">PIDS</a></li>
 <li><a href="products/enterprise/zeus.php" class="footer-content-link">QMS</a></li>
```

The result after I click it first worked, but after clicking it the second time, here's what came out:

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Here's a sample file path after clicking one:
products/enterprise/products/enterprise/zeus.php

The `.htaccess` file

```
 # Turn mod_rewrite on 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 

 # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo 
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

 # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: prefix each url with `/`

Comment: Thank you, but this still comes out after first click: The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Comment: do you have a `htaccess` file with `rewrite` rules?

Comment: We have no idea where the files are located on your server, or where they are located relative to the page you are running here. Perhaps you could show us your folder structure, and then we might be able to suggest the correct URL. Meanwhile you can also check what the fully-qualified URL being generated by your browser is after clicking on one of these links, and see if it looks like how you've expected.

Comment: @RamRaider I have the htaccess.bak with the rewrite rules

Comment: the `.bak` extension suggests a backup made by a text editor - is there `.htaccess` file though without the `bak` extension? Note that it is `.htaccess` ~ this issue seems to me like a rewrite rule issue

Comment: Here is the full code for the htaccess @RamRaider:

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Comment: @ADyson here is the URL/file path : C:\xampp\htdocs\tigerweb\products\enterprise

Comment: You could confirm whether or not this is an htaccess issue by commenting out the rewrite rules or by turning them off `RewriteEngine Off` - if the problem persists then likely another issue

Comment: I have turned the RewriteEngine Off, and the problem is still there. What are the other issues needed to address? Thanks!!! :D

Comment: " here is the URL/file path" ...URL is not the same as file path at all. What is the folder configured as the root of your website? Where is your HTML/PHP page located relative to the files you're trying to load? That's what I was asking. It's all about relative paths. Its absolute location on disk is irrelevant when talking about URLs.

Comment: @ADyson it is located on my htdocs folder wherein I put all of the files in. Are you talking about the one in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: No, your database has nothing to do with this. Anyway, so if the page is stored in `htdocs` as you mention, then what URL do you use to access the page where this HTML is located? e.g something like `http://localhost/yourpage.php` maybe? If so, then according to what you've told me, the URL to your other pages **relative to that** ought to be `tigerweb/products/enterprise/zeus.php` because that is the path from htdocs downwards to that location. If the page was located in the `tigerweb` folder then the path you've shown in the question ought to be the correct one.

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046543/object-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-localhost