# Linking html href in laravel

Tags: html, laravel

Please i have converted my html website into a laravel 7 project and the home page is working fine.but my navigation is not working neither any of the links

```
<a href="/Herbal_Doctor" >Herbal Doctor</a>
```

my route is

```
Route::get('/Herbal_Doctor', function () {
    return view('Herbal_Doctor');
});
```

I have have created route for them yet it throws me this error. Please help fix this problem.

> Object not found!
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> Error 404
> localhost**

Comment: that looks like a web server 404 not a Laravel 404, sounds like webserver is not configured correctly

Comment: can try type `php artisan route:list` on terminal/cmd? see if GET /Herbal_Doctor is exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Route::get('Herbal_Doctor'
```

Remove slash

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_

Comment: @JohnKyei can you execute "php artisan route:list" command from root of your laravel project? And you will see all available paths

Comment: @JohnKyei mybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046543/object-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-localhost

Comment: yhh is now working  but my Home nav is not working . when i try to open it from any of the pages. This is the code im using for my Home Navigation. This is not working from any of the pages either. please help. <a href="index" >Home</a>

Comment: This is the route im using for the home page  |                                                  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});