# Problem with datatable ajax pagination, it give undefined url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

it give out:

> http://localhost/aps/undefined Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.11

```
//The php code to fetch data
<?php
include('db.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT * FROM users ";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["first_name"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["last_name"];
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>

//javasrcipt jquery
var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[0, 3, 4],
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ]

    });
```

Comment: Maybe this link help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046543/object-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-localhost
Did you check if the file is in the right position in htdocs folder of your local webserver

Comment: NO, my ht docs is RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
php_flag register_globals 0
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 0 
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime 0

Comment: Not the .htaccess settings. I mean if the file is physically in the folder like xampp/htdocs/aps/yourfile.php
This is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check if your local webserver is working properly. Just place a file call it e.g. info.php with the following content in xampp/htdocs:

```php
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Call it with localhost/info.php in your browser and see if the content is like this:
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

Check also if your webserver still runs or runs at all.

That's good.

```js
var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    paging: true,
    "ajax":{
        url:"fetch.php",
        type:"POST",
         success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        // handle success
         },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           // handle error
         }
        } 
    })
});
```

Maybe paging: true is the solution.
The 404 Error is related to the ajax call. I found it in the docs.
Sorry but I'm not familiar with DataTables. Try to get a specific failure with the handler. You should search and read https://datatables.net/forums/

Comment: My web app is located in the htdocs will all pages, the page which display a datatable is also in the same folder i.e localhost/aps/datatable.php and the table display as well but the problem arise when I click pagination links they give out new page which is  localhost/aps/undefined what is the problem?

Comment: I added paging: true, it worked @Bernhard Beatus, also there were some errors at the end of js file look at the above